# Phonegap - FileReader doesn't invoke/load

Tags: android, jquery, phonegap-plugins, filereader

I have a requirement to upload a photo in to server using mobile APP. Where I use the following code to read the the file.

```
if (filesSelected.length > 0)
                {
                    alert("lenth great than zero");
                    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

                    var fileReader = new FileReader();

                    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

                        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
                        newImage.src = srcData;
                        base64_string = newImage.outerHTML;
                        alert(srcData + "srouce data  now");

                    }
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
                    *** SERVICE CALL Comes Here ***
                }
```

from the code filesSelected.length returns the value greater zero (0) all the time (ie, if the image is available) and alerts the "lenth great than zero" and doesn't alert srcData + "srouce data  now".

I guess the fileReader is not invoking/called after it. So can anyone help me in fixing this issue.

Please let me know if you need any thing more from the code.

Comment: which version are you using.The file API has been updated. can u try   fileReader.onloadend instead of  fileReader.onload. if this doesn't work let us know phonegap version?

Comment: is there permission to read/write in manifest.xml

Comment: @Akki619, let me give a try with fileReader.onloadend now and get back to you

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev, YES manifest.xml has its permission

Comment: @Akki619, onloadend worked for me, but var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; results me the null value for srcData...

Comment: @KiranKumar, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

there is another method(which is `onloadend`, isn't `onload`) to load in cordova/phonegap API 3.6.0 documentation. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

```
function win(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        console.log("read success");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};

var fail = function (evt) {
    console.log(error.code);
};

entry.file(win, fail);
```

Comment: evt.target.result doesn't log anything, it says undefined, do we have any alternative like onloadend instead of onload.

Comment: onloadend: Called when the request has completed (either in success or failure). (Function)

Comment: You should use onloadend method

Comment: onload: Called when the read has successfully completed. (Function)

- it is from documentation.

Comment: I don't find other from documentation. Maybe, there is other problem if onloadend isn't working